# How do you start and end reading a file at a specific string in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, text, file-io

How do you start and end reading a file at a specific string?

For example:

```
start file
some data
start point
some data
end point
some data
end file
```

I'm at this so far:

```
filename = 'name of file'
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in iter(lambda: f.readline().rstrip(), 'end point'):
        print(line)
```

Comment: Is the example the contents of your input file? What would the expected output be?

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on if you're reading n lines, or reading all lines until a specific line containing a substring is encountered.

Three examples:

```py
# Ready file until 'end point' is encountered in a line
with open('sample.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    # ... do things with the line
    print(line)
    if 'end point' in line:
      print('---')
      break

# Read the first 5 lines
with open('sample.txt') as f:
  lines = [next(f) for x in range(5)]
  print(lines)

# Less performant, read all lines and then slice
with open('sample.txt') as f:
  all_lines = f.readlines()
  print(lines[:5])
```

Comment: I need code that will start at a certain string, and end at another certain string.